# $k\to\oplus A_i\to k'$, is it true that $k\to k'$ factors through one of $A_i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$, $k'$ be fields. Suppose a non-zero ring homomorphism $k\to k'$ factors through a direct sum of finitely many artinian local rings $A_i$, $k\to\oplus A_i\to k'$. Is it true that $k\to k'$ factors through one of $A_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k$ has nothing to do with this problem; it's true more generally that if $A = \prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ is a finite product of commutative rings and $D$ is a [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_ring) commutative ring (a ring with no nontrivial idempotents, e.g. any integral domain), then any morphism $f : A \to D$ factors through one of the $A_i$. This is because, among the idempotents $e_i = (0, 0, \dots 1, \dots 0) \in \prod A_i$, exactly one can map to the identity in $D$, and the rest must map to zero.

Geometrically, this says that $\text{Hom}(\text{Spec } D, -)$ commutes with finite coproducts in the category of affine schemes. This is a slight weakening of the usual notion of a [connected object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+object).

Comment: If two idempotents are mapped to $1$,what would be the contradiction?

Comment: @mqx: the idempotents $e_i$ sum to $1 \in A$, and hence $f(\sum e_i) = \sum f(e_i) = 1$. Now each $f(e_i)$ is also an idempotent, hence by assumption can only be $0$ or $1$. At least one of them, say $e_j$, must map to $1$. Then the fact that $e_i e_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$ shows that $f(e_i e_j) = f(e_i) f(e_j) = 0$ if $i \neq j$, hence $f(e_i)$ must be $0$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Much more generally, the functor sending a commutative ring to its idempotents can be upgraded to take values in Boolean rings, and I'm just describing a proof that any morphism $\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2$ of Boolean rings is a projection, or said another way that any ultrafilter on a finite set is principal.